# Probability of Drawing Three of a Kind and a Joker

Tags: probability, combinations, poker

In a standard deck of cards plus 1 additional joker (53 cards), I am trying to calculate the probability of drawing a Three of a Kind and a Joker in the same 5 card hand.

At the moment I know the probability for drawing a three of a kind is:

${^{13}\mathrm C_1}\times{^4\mathrm C_3}\times{^{12}\mathrm C_2}\times({^4\mathrm C_1})^2 ~/~ {^{53}\mathrm C_5}$

I am just wondering how I would add in the joker

(this is for school and any help would very appreciated)

Comment: Do you mean Ace Ace Ace Joker King (which would be 4 Aces) or Ace Ace Joker King Queen?

Answer (score 1):

One of the non-3-of-a-kind cards must be the Joker, so in your notation $$\dfrac{\,^{13}C_1 \times \,^{4}C_3\times \,^{12}C_1 \times \,^{4}C_1 \times \,^{1}C_1}{\,^{53}C_5}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability for obtaining *three from four* suits in *one from thirteen* kinds **and** *two other cards*, when selecting *five from fifty-three* cards is actually:$$\def\C#1#2{\mathop{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}}\dfrac{\C{13}{1}\times\C 43\times\left(\C{12}2\times\C42^2+\C{12}1\times\C41\times\C11\right) }{\C{53}5}$$

**Note:** those *two other cards* are either: *two from four* suits in each of *two from twelve* kinds, **or** *one from four* suits in *one from twelve* kinds *and the joker*.